# Dice Game of two players

Tags: probability

There are two players playing a dice game. Assume player 1 rolls first and the game will end until either player rolls a 6. What is the probability that player 2 wins the game?
I can calculate the probability using the sum of a geometric sequence. Could someone explain this question in a more intuitive way? Thank you very much,

Comment: when do I win the game? when I get 6 or when my adversary gets 6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If player 1 gets anything other than a 6, then we are effectively in the same position as we were before, but with the players roles swapped.

So Player 2's chance of winning is $5/6$ that of player 1's chance of winning.

So the chances of winning must be $6/11$ for player 1 and $5/11$ for player 2.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the first player to roll a $6$ wins.

Let $p$ be the probability that Player $1$ wins.  Then $1-p$ is the probability that player $2$ wins.  But if Player $1$ rolls anything but a $6$ on the first roll (which happens with probability $\frac 56$), then Player $2$ is now in the same position Player $1$ was in at the start of the game.  On the other hand, if Player $1$ does roll a $6$, then the probability that Player $2$ wins the game is $0$.

Therefore, $1-p= \frac 56 p + \frac 16 \cdot 0$, so $p = \frac{6}{11}$ and $1-p= \frac{5}{11}$.